# What does git do, when I push a local branch that does not exist on remote server?

Tags: git

I have a vanilla git installation with default configuration, version 1.7.1.

So I do the following actions:

```
git branch local_only
git checkout local_only
git push
```

`local_only` does not exist on remote.

The `push` command takes *several* seconds to complete, and eventually tells me 'Everything up-to-date'. I would like to understand what `push` actually does in this situation:

- If git was checking whether remote branch exists, why does it not return an error? OR
- If git was not checking whether remote branch exists or not, why did it take several seconds, and return a success response?

`git branch -avv` output:

```
* local_only            ...commit...
master                  ...commit...
remotes/origin/master   ...commit...
```

Comment: Oops, wasn't there any message *after* sha1 and *before* commit message? The command is expected to print upstream branch like `origin/tex`. Well, what does `git push -v` say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to push it like this:

```
git branch local_only
git checkout local_only
git push origin
```

Then it will create a remote branch and remote origin repository. See more at paragraph "Pushing" here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

---

Concerning question what does git do when you 'git push'. According to this [article](http://blogs.collab.net/git/protect-git-history) 'git push' is equivalent to 'git push origin master:master'. So it should check your origin/master branch and update it if you have something new in master, regardless of the brunch you are currently on.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was asking what Git would do given the (incorrect) push action.

Comment: "given the (incorrect) push action"?  I think you mean "the undesired push action in my case", since git only does what it is told to do.  Review git config push.default.

Comment: @Howard Guo, I made an addition to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a setting called push.default (`git config push.default`).

Pre Git 2.0, the default is `matching`, which means that git will push any branch that also exists on the remote.  After Git 2.0, the default isn't set, and git suggests you set it to `simple`.

So if you create a new branch, and you do git push, it won't push that branch because it doesn't exist yet on the remote.

In newer versions of git, they'll change the default to `simple`, which pushes the current branch to the upstream branch for that branch, but only if they have the same name.

See also [git config](http://jk.gs/git-config.html):

> push.default
>   Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly
>   given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for
>   instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal
>   to the push destination), upstream is probably what you want.

In all these cases, you first have to explicitly push the new branch (`git push <remote> <branch>`), and some do require an upstream (`git push -u <remote> <branch>`).